# Problem using 'anova_fun' argument in 'add_global_p()'

Tags: r, p-value, gtsummary

I'm tying to display the results of analysis-of-variance applied to univariate regressions into a table created with `gtsummary::tbl_uvregression()` using another function than `car::Anova()`, that cannot handle every type of models. In my case I would like to use `Anova.clm()` from `RVAideMemoire` package, which is directly based on `car::Anova()` function and specifically built for clm(m) objects.

Unfortunately, any time I try to use `anova_fun` argument of `add_global_p()`, I get an error telling me that `mod` (the model) should be specified into the function with no default value. I read the documentation of `add_global_p()`, and in fact it is specified that the "anova_fun" function is used "in place of car::Anova()" and that it must accept a model as one of its arguments. But as far as I know, `Anova.clm()` uses it.
Moreover, the thing is even when I try to use `car::Anova()` itself through the `anova_fun` argument, I still get the same error. I also tried to go through the source codes of the different functions I need here, but couldn't find the solution and begin to get lost...

Here a reprex :

```
## Load packages
library(survival)
library(gtsummary)

## Create the table using tbl_uvregression
tab <- trial %>% 
  select(response,age,trt) %>%
  tbl_uvregression(method = glm,
                   method.args = list(family = binomial),
                   y = response,
                   exponentiate = T) 

## Add global p-values from analysis-of-variance through 'anova_fun' argument
tab %>%
  add_global_p(anova_fun = car::Anova)

## And the same for tbl_regression
trial %>% 
  glm(response ~ age + trt, data = ., family = binomial("logit")) %>%
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = T) %>%
  add_global_p(anova_fun = car::Anova)
```

Maybe I just misunderstand the use of `anova_fun` argument into `add_global_p()`... In that case could somebody help me to deal with it ? Or at least is there an other (simple) way to add aov global p-values to a `tbl_uvregression` object applied to clmm models ?

Comment: The help file describes the required inputs for the `anova_fun=` argument. "function must return a tibble matching the output of `car::Anova() %>% broom::tidy()`." https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/add_global_p.html

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg thanks for your quick answer. I saw this as well, but the error I get seems to focus more into the input of the function (model argument missing for the "anova" function) than the output. And even when I pass 'car::Anova() %>% broom::tidy()' into 'anova_fun', it doesn't solve the problem...

Comment: You have to pass a proper function

Comment: Wow, didn't think it could just be due to that. I should have tried it earlier, so much time lost for a so simple solution... Anyway, thanks a lot for your help !