# How to use car::Anova in tbl_uvregression?

Tags: gtsummary

I am trying to use a gee like the following code:

```
example <- trial%>%
  na.omit()%>%
  tbl_uvregression(
    method = geepack::geeglm,
    y = death,
    method.args = list(
      family = binomial,
      id = grade,
      corstr = "independence"),
    exponentiate = TRUE,
    add_estimate_to_reference_rows = T,
    conf.level = 0.95)
```

Which works just fine and gives me desired univariate analysis for all Xs. However, when I try to use add_global_p, I get the following error: There was an error running `car::Anova()` for "trt", likely due to this model type not being supported. The results displayed are based on `add_global_p(anova_fun = gtsummary::tidy_wald_test)`. This also happens to all Xs. However, I know for sure this model is supported by car::Anova since I used it with geeglm (see example 1 down):

```
example1 <- trial%>%na.omit()

example1.outcome <- geepack::geeglm(death ~ trt,family = binomial,id = grade,corstr = "independence", data = example1)
car::Anova(example1.outcome, type = 3, test.statistic = "Wald")
```

Outcome:

Analysis of Deviance table (Type III tests)
Response: death

| variable | Df | Chisq | Pr(>chisq) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| intercept | 1 | 0.28 | 0.6 |
| trt | 1 | 2.03 | 0.15 |

Going back to example, I tried a few different things such as:

```
example%>%
    add_global_p(car::Anova(type = 3, test.statistic = "Chisq"))
```

But it gives the following error: Error in car::Anova(type = 3, test.statistic = "Chisq") :
argument "mod" is missing, with no default.

I also tried:

```
add_global_p(car::Anova(example, type = 3, test.statistic = "Chisq"))
```

but the following error arises: Error in UseMethod("vcov") :
no applicable method for 'vcov' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_uvregression', 'gtsummary')"

I also tried:

```
example%>%
    add_global_p(anova_fun= car::Anova)
```

But it says argument mod is missing. I tried a few different things, but I do not seem to be able to get it. I also looked at the following question, and still could not figure it out: [Problem using 'anova_fun' argument in 'add_global_p()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75301035/problem-using-anova-fun-argument-in-add-global-p)

Bonus: I am also wondering if it would be possible to add the values of Chisq test (the 3rd column in the output of example 1) in a column next to p-values.

Comment: Please update your post with a minimal reproducible example (ie code and data we can run on our machines). Welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg Hello Daniel ! I updated the post. Let me know if it is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below for a working example:

```r
library(gtsummary)

tbl <-
  trial %>%
  na.omit()%>%
  tbl_uvregression(
    method = geepack::geeglm,
    y = death,
    include = response,
    method.args = list(
      family = binomial,
      id = grade,
      corstr = "independence"),
    exponentiate = TRUE,
    add_estimate_to_reference_rows = T,
    conf.level = 0.95
  )

# this is the geepack::geeglm() model
class(tbl$tbls$response$model_obj)
#> [1] "geeglm" "gee"    "glm"    "lm"

# not compatible with `car::Anova()`
car::Anova(tbl$tbls$response$model_obj)
#> Error in glm.control(trace = 0L, jack = 0L, j1s = 0L, fij = 0L, maxit = 25L, : unused arguments (jack = 0, j1s = 0, fij = 0)

# the non-compatibility is shown below from within gtsummary
tbl_error <- tbl %>% add_global_p()
#> ✖ There was an error running `car::Anova()` for "response", likely due to this model type not being supported. The results displayed are based on `add_global_p(anova_fun = gtsummary::tidy_wald_test)`

# as the error message indicates, use the tidy_wald_test() function to get around the error
# FYI, this function was written FOR geepack models
tbl %>%
  add_global_p(anova_fun = gtsummary::tidy_wald_test) %>%
  as_kable() # convert to kable so it will display on StackOverflow
```

| **Characteristic** | **N** | **OR** | **95% CI** | **p-value** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tumor Response | 173 | 0.35 | 0.19, 0.66 | <0.001 |

<sup>Created on 2023-06-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hello Daniel. Thanks for your answer, I appreciate it ! I am wondering if it is possible to display the test statistic(z value) as well and not only the p-value?

Comment: The ANOVA function above does return the test statistic in addition to the value, but it's not available to print by default. You'll need to add it manually with add_stat()